# Difference between the classes inherited from ObservableCollection and IList

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm, observablecollection

I have created the two different classes. One class inherited from IList and another one class inherited from ObservableCollection. When we create the instance for those classes, I got the below results.

**Inherited from IList**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cells = new CellCollection();
    }

    private CellCollection cells;

    public CellCollection Cells
    {
        get { return cells; }
        set { cells = value; }
    }
}

public class CellCollection : IList<OrderInfo>
{
    public CellCollection()
    {
    }

    public OrderInfo this[int index] { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }



    public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(OrderInfo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(OrderInfo[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<OrderInfo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(OrderInfo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, OrderInfo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(OrderInfo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void Add(OrderInfo orderInfo)
    {
        
    }

    void ICollection<OrderInfo>.Add(OrderInfo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image: Instance maintained for IList]

**Instance maintained for IList.**

**Inherited from ObservableCollection**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cells = new CellCollection();
    }

    private CellCollection cells;

    public CellCollection Cells
    {
        get { return cells; }
        set { cells = value; }
    }
}

public class CellCollection : ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>
{
    public CellCollection()
    {

    }


}
```

[image: Instance not maintained for Observable collection, Count only maintained]

**Instance not maintained for Observable collection, Count only maintained**

Could you explain the difference for both?

Answer (score 1):

The debugger makes use of the [debugger attributes](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=debugdisplay+atribute) the type is annotated with.
If a type does not use these attributes, the `ToString()` method of that type is called to get a text representation.

The `ObservableCollection` uses one of these methods to display the `Count`. Your own `List` implementation does none of this, so the base `ToString()` method is called which only returns the type name.

So to get a similar result for your own type, implement `ToString()` or annotate your `CellCollection` class with a `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

When the cursor is over a variable, you can see the variable name and the instance's debug label.

By default, the debug label is the result of `ToString`. For your class `CellList`, the method `ToString` cam from the base class `Object` and return the class's name. This display : **CellList**.

The attribute [DebuggerDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute) allows define the instance's debug label (not to string). The class `CellCollection` inherit from `ObservableCollection<T>` than inherit from `Collection<T>` and [the class Collection is declared with the attribute DebuggerDisplay](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs#L20).

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Count = {Count}")]    
public class Collection<T>: IList<T>, IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
```

It's the same with all collection in .NET, like List.

If you set this attribute on your class `CellList`, you will see the same debug label.